# Finding areas of beings in microscopic image

Tags: image-processing

I've got lots of images of diatoms. I need to get a list of their equivalent radii.

[image: some diatoms]

[image: more diatoms]

It's not crucial to get them all, as long as those missed don't mess with the radius distribution (as would happen if it always missed the biggest ones or the smallest ones).

I am having trouble mainly because sometimes two little beings end up overlapping, in which case I would need to either separate them or at least discard them. Also, even though some may look like hollow, or even split in two, they are actually one. So

```
images = Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7vag.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQJlW.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGTro.jpg"};

preproc[im_] := 
 ColorConvert[im, "GrayScale"] // Binarize // ColorNegate // 
    FillingTransform // MorphologicalComponents // Colorize

FlipView[{#, preproc @ #}] & /@ images // TabView
```

[image: diatoms after image processing]

An example of an image with the beings approximately rounded manually can be seen here:

[image: measuring the diatoms]

I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Note: a semi-automatic solution can still save a lot of time

Comment: [This Wolfram blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) shows an example of separating overlapping cells.

Comment: Perhaps the property that they are "usually almost bilaterally symmetrical" (Wikipedia) can be used to detect overlapping particles.

Comment: Why are they all in lines? Are they playing follow-the-leader?

Comment: Another relevant [Wolfram blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/09/09/building-a-microscopy-application-in-mathematica/).

Comment: @bills they like to live in colonies, but I wonder if there's a mother duck among the ducklings :P

Comment: @BoLe thanks! I'm taking a look

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries thank you too. From a cursory glance it seems they use the same `MaxDetect@DistanceTransform` trick to separate overlapping blobs as in Bole's blog

Comment: OT: I encountered a similar problem years ago. When I was trying to figure out, my boss got tired and bought a 15,000USD software for it..(Before that, we count them manually.)

Comment: Try with an [easier organism first](http://farm1.staticflickr.com/90/208997985_692784c75f_z.jpg?zz=1)

Comment: @Silvia, if you give me 15000U$D I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: I say we find a third guy who would like to answer your question and mine separately :DD

Comment: I think you should try doing it in a colorspace other than "Grayscale". Check this: `Prepend[ColorSeparate[img,#],#]&/@{"Intensity","Blue","Saturation","Mean","XYZ"}//Grid`.

Comment: btw I took an [image processing course on coursera](https://class.coursera.org/images-2012-001/lecture/index) 3 month ago, and I think some technic there you might found helpful. I would highly recommend the *Active Contours* method on week 5 (also [ref](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/g-cv/)), and all *Geometric PDEs* methods on week 6.

Comment: I also suggest the cluster method based on histogram in colorspace in this [Wolfram blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/09/seeing-skin-with-mathematica/), though you'll have to training a database first.

Comment: @Silvia I've signed up for the course :P. Hope I have the time

Answer (score 59):

**EDIT**: I've found a bug in the code; Now the result looks a lot better, too.

This isn't perfect, but it's a start.

The first step is to find the "chain elements" (what are those anyway? I'm guessing cells?)

The chain elements have a distinctive scale, so I can filter them out easily using a median filter:

[image]

Subtracting the median filtered image from the original removes the background:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGTro.jpg"];
(* I apply the median filter to a downsampled image - the result is almost the 
   same, but it's much much faster this way *)
diff = ImageAdjust[
   ImageDifference[
    ImageResize[MedianFilter[ImageResize[img, 250], 10], 
     ImageDimensions[img][[1]]], img]]
```

[image]

I don't want to work with RGB images, so I simply take the mean of the three channels. (`ColorConvert[..., "Grayscale"]` doesn't make much sense here, since these aren't "natural" colors, where the green channel contains most of the brightness).

```
meanImg = Total[ImageData[diff], {-1}]/3;
```

To find the centers of the chain links, I use a laplacian of gaussian filter, with a filter size that's approximately as large as the chain links themselves.

```
σ = 25;
log = Image[LaplacianGaussianFilter[meanImg, σ]*-σ^2]
```

[image]

I'm looking for local maxima in this image that are brighter than some threshold:

```
maxima = ImageMultiply[MaxDetect[log], Binarize[log, 0.5]];    
pts = ComponentMeasurements[maxima, "Centroid"][[All, 2]];
```

This finds the maxima, but the list contains some "duplicates", where the same object contains multiple maxima in the LoG image. I can remove those relatively easily by using Mathematica's `MeanShift` function to "cluster" points that are close together, then removing duplicate points:

```
pts = Union[MeanShift[pts, 25, MaxIterations -> 10]];
```

In addition to the chain element centers, I'd like to have an estimate of the direction at each point. I can get a good estimate using calculus (I calculate the angle of the major eigenvector of the Hessian matrix at each point):

```
Clear[gaussianDerivative];
Do[gaussianDerivative[i, 2 - i] = 
   GaussianFilter[meanImg, 2 σ, {i, 2 - i}], {i, 0, 2}];

angles = Image[
   ArcTan @@ 
     Eigenvectors[{{m[0, 2], m[1, 1]}, {m[1, 1], m[2, 0]}}][[1]] /. 
    m -> gaussianDerivative];

getDirectionAt = 
  Function[pt, 
   With[{α = π/2 - ImageValue[angles, pt]}, {Cos[α],
      Sin[α]}]];
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
   Line[{# - 15 getDirectionAt[#], # + 15 getDirectionAt[#]}] & /@ 
    pts}]]
```

[image]

Now the idea is to :

- pick a point at random
- pick it's nearest neighbor
- estimate where the next point in the chain would be - if there's a point close to that location, add it to the list
- rinse and repeat until no more points are found

This is the code:

```
nf = Nearest[pts];
continueChain = Function[chain,
   Module[{expectedNextPoint, nearestNextPoint, direction},
    (
     direction = chain[[-1]] - chain[[-2]];
     expectedNextPoint = chain[[-1]] + direction;
     nearestNextPoint = nf[expectedNextPoint][[1]];
     If[
      Norm[nearestNextPoint - expectedNextPoint] < 
        Norm[direction]*0.75 &&
       Abs[
         getDirectionAt[chain[[-1]]].getDirectionAt[
           nearestNextPoint]] > 0.5 &&
       Norm[direction] < 100
      , Append[chain, nearestNextPoint], chain]
     )]];

findRandomChain[] := Module[{chain},
  (
   chain = nf[RandomChoice[pts], 2];
   chain = FixedPoint[continueChain, chain];
   chain = FixedPoint[continueChain, Reverse[chain]]
   )]
```

This function finds one random chain. If I call it often enough, I'll (almost always) get all of the potential chains:

```
allChains = 
  SortBy[Union[Table[findRandomChain[], {1000}]], -Length[#] &];
```

The only problem is that some of those chains "overlap", i.e. some points are members of more than one chain. I think a good solution to this problem would be to apply a mixture of gaussians/expectation maximization algorithm to decide which point belongs to which chain. But it's getting late here, so I'll just go with a simple greedy algorithm:

- Start with the longest chain
- remove the points from the chain that are already used in some other chain
- If the chain still contains at least two or more points, keep it
- Remove all points in this chain from the set of "unused" points
- repeat for all chains

This is it:

```
removeChainPoints = Function[{unusedPoints, chain},
   With[{modifiedChain = Select[chain, MemberQ[unusedPoints, #] &]},
    (
     If[Length[modifiedChain] >= 2, Sow[modifiedChain]];
     Complement[unusedPoints, chain]
     )]];
noOverlap = Reap[Fold[removeChainPoints, pts, allChains]][[2, 1]];
```

Now, noOverlap contains a set of non-overlapping chains:

```
totalChainLength = Total[Norm /@ Differences[#]] &;
colorFn = ColorData[3];
Show[
 ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"],
 Graphics[
  MapThread[
   Module[{direction, normal},
     (
      direction = #1[[1]] - #1[[-1]];
      direction = direction/Norm[direction];
      normal = {-direction[[2]], direction[[1]]};
      {
       colorFn[#2],
       Thick,
       Line[#1],
       Dotted,
       Line[{#1[[1]], #1[[1]] + 50*normal, #1[[-1]] + 
          50*normal, #1[[-1]]}],
       Text[totalChainLength[#1], Mean[#1] + 50*normal]
       }
      )] &,
   {noOverlap, Range[Length[noOverlap]]}]]]
```

[image]

I didn't spend much time optimizing the thresholds in `continueChain`, so you could try to improve those. But you could probably come up with a smarter algorithm than simply adding one nearest point after the other. There's probably a well-known graph algorithm that will find globally optimal solutions in no time. (`FindCurvePath` *almost* does what I want, but I couldn't find a way to tweak the algorithm, so it groups far too many points into one curve.)

This is the result for the other image:

[image]

Comment: Wow, fantastic!

Comment: Many biologists thank you!  Superb!

Comment: "The first step is to find the "chain elements" (what are those anyway? I'm guessing cells?)" - yep, those are diatom cells. That particular species just aggregates that way.

Comment: @nikie you know, i'd pay good money for an image processing book if you wrote it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot nikie for this answer. It helps, and most importantly is very instructive as all of your image processing answers are. I am still struggling to detect the borders of the cells and their areas, but I'm enjoying testing some ideas that more or less work.

Comment: wow @nikie, thank you so much! This is really nice and, you can only imagine, **so useful**

Comment: Very useful. Good job.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this beautiful answer! I recently posted a similar question but for an image of particle systems, where the aim is to detect the underlying connectivity graph of the particles. Here is the post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/203517 , it already contains a wonderful answer, but it starts from the basic binarization I had considered. I was wondering if you had ideas for how to extend that approach (or a new one) in order to take into account the 3D aspect of the image, namely that some particles can be seen to be at higher or lower depth (visible from brightness too).