# Clustering edge points of an image?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

Consider the following image

[image]

I would like to cluster the points obtained after edge detection and subsequently, would like to color the clustered edge points.

**My attempt:**

```
img = URLExecute["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q309.png"];
edgeImg = img // EdgeDetect;
edgePoints = PixelValuePositions[edgeImg, 1];
clusteredEdgePoints = FindClusters[edgePoints, Method -> "NeighborhoodContraction"];
{edgeImg, Graphics[{ColorData["DarkRainbow"][RandomReal[]], Line[#]} & /@ 
   clusteredEdgePoints]}
```

> {[image], [image]}

**Question:**

One can observe, [`FindClusters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) did not group inner and outer ellipses. How should I tell [`FindClusters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) to group inner and outer ellipses? or is there any other alternative?

Note: I would like to keep the question as general as possible that is I would not want to enter the number of clusters explicitly.

Some other images can be as follows:

```
img1 = URLExecute["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z150N.png"];
img2 = URLExecute["https://i.stack.imgur.com/spkHI.png"];
```

[image],
[image]

Comment: Consider something like `FindClusters[edgePoints, 2, Method -> "Agglomerate", 
 CriterionFunction -> "RSquared"]`. Playing around with `Method` and `CriterionFunction` is worthwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to find connected components of all edge pixels that are less than N pixels apart?

You could use `MorphologicalComponents` for this:

```
MorphologicalComponents[Dilation[edgeImg, 5]]*
  ImageData[edgeImg] // Colorize
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to connect the clustered edge points using Lines too. I have tried this: `Graphics[Line@
  Position[MorphologicalComponents[Dilation[edgeImg, 5]], 1]]`, but it gives a black image. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I realized that points obtained using `Position[MorphologicalComponents[Dilation[edgeImg, 5]], 1]`  are not ordered. Is there a way I could order them?

Comment: @AnjanKumar: I wouldn't go down that route - there are too many morphological special cases and pitfalls. (Take e.g. the two little line segments at the bottom of the O image above - where would you connect them to?) It's way simpler to use something like `MorphologicalPerimeter[img]` that is guaranteed to return closed contours than using `EdgeDetect` and then trying to reconstruct them

Comment: If you only have a point set and need to find connected components, your best bet is using graph algorithms (see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95425/can-i-get-the-curvature-at-any-point-of-a-random-curve/95442#95442, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80683/reconstruction-of-interrupted-paths-in-images/88579#88579). But as you can see, this is much more complicated than using a function returning closed contours, like `ContourDetect`, `ZeroCrossings` or `MorphologicalPerimeter`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried: `MorphologicalPerimeter[img // Binarize]`, it does seem to return closed contours, however, I am not sure how to get the contour points for the inner and outer ellipses. Do I have to apply `MorphologicalComponents[]` on top of this?

Comment: So you don't want "clusters" (i.e. sets of connected points), but ordered contours? You could just use `ComponentMeasurements[img, "Contours"]` for that

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I want.