# Reconstruct a graph from an image (curved edges and edge crossings)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, image

Actually, I posted a very similar question before this.[How to generate a Graph from a picture of a graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102262/how-to-generate-a-graph-from-a-picture-of-a-graph?lq=1)

*Dr. belisarius*'s answer have answered that question, but I find a limitation in that method: If the image of the graph contains curved edges, the method given to my previous question will not work.

For example, consider a pictrue like following:

[image]

I would like to know how to handle the issues raised by having curved edges.

Comment: Well, of course [**the general case isn't well defined**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o7O43.png) So I believe you should work first on the restrictions before giving the problem away to potential answerers

Comment: [This blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/21/the-battle-of-the-marlborough-maze-at-blenheim-palace-continues/) might have some possibilities. See also [this excellent Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FromImagesToGraphsMorphologicalGraphs/) or [this one](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UrbanRoadNetworks/) by the late Jaime Rangel-Mondragon.

Comment: Hope my strabismic bosom doesn't offend anyone

Comment: @Dr.belisarius great, now I cannot unsee that.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius No,Not about your strabismic bosom.But I don't think a normal `Graph` will be that your loaded picture(even though It is a real `Graph` with two ring.).

Comment: @yode That's the whole point. You should define "normal", in geometric terms

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Without claiming much generality, I made the following. I'm using a slightly more complex image than your proposed one.

```
i = Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDby8.png";
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
idi                  = ImageDimensions@i;
vertexI              = SelectComponents[i, "Count", 5 < # < 100 &];
disk                 = 20 (*use some heuristics to ensure a proper vertex occlusion radii*);
p[disk_, fraction_] := IntegerPart[disk fraction](*proportionalty*)
g[x_, r___]         := Graphics[x, PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, idi}], 
                                   ImageSize -> idi, r]
vxRules              = ComponentMeasurements[vertexI, "Centroid"];
vxPos                = Range@Length@vxRules/. vxRules;

i1 = Binarize[Show[i, g[{White, Disk[#, disk] & /@ vxPos}]]];
i2 = ColorNegate@Erosion[i1, 1];
getMask[edges_, edge_] := SelectComponents[edges, {"Label", "Mask"}, #1 == edge &];
edges = MorphologicalComponents@DeleteSmallComponents[i2, 30];

(* masks "preserve" the mask number*)
masks = getMask[edges, #] & /@ Range@Max@Flatten@edges;

ImageAdd[#, g[{Red, (Disk[#1, disk] &) /@ vxPos}, Background -> Black]] & /@ 
                                                                  (Image /@ masks)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* tm may require Pruning[tm, nn] if the image is low quality *)
tm  = Thinning@Image@Total@masks;
mbp = MorphologicalTransform[Binarize@tm, "SkeletonBranchPoints"];

(* get the "unique" branch points, like clustering by taking the mean of near points*)
mbpClustered =  Union@MeanShift[ImageValuePositions[mbp, 1], p[disk, 1/2]];

(* Get the whole image of all multiples occluding branch points*)
segs = ImageMultiply[tm, Binarize@g[{Black, Disk[#1, p[disk, 1/4]] & /@ mbpClustered}]];
mcsegs = MorphologicalComponents[segs];

mcsegs // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm pretty sure the following function can be done better, for example by using [@nikie's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25206/193)

```
findContinuations[branchPoint_, i_, mcsegs_, disk_] := 
 Module[{mm, coSegs, segmentsAtBranchPoint, tails, tgs, dests, a, b, x}, 
   mm    = Binarize@Image[g[{White, Disk[branchPoint, p[disk, 2/5]]}, 
                         Background -> Black], ImageSize -> idi];
  coSegs = ImageMultiply[Image@mcsegs, mm] ;
  segmentsAtBranchPoint = Select[Union@Flatten[ImageData@coSegs], # != 0 &];
  tails  = Position[ImageData@coSegs, #] & /@ segmentsAtBranchPoint;
  tgs    = a /. FindFit[#, a x + b, {a, b}, x] & /@ tails;
  dests  = Nearest[tgs -> segmentsAtBranchPoint, #, 2][[2]] & /@ tgs;
  Sort /@ Transpose[{segmentsAtBranchPoint, dests}] // Union]



fc         = findContinuations[#, i, mcsegs, disk] & /@ mbpClustered;
equiv      = Flatten /@ Gather[Flatten[fc, 1], Intersection[#1, #2] =!= {} &];
rules      = Reverse /@ Thread[First@# -> Rest@#] & /@ IntegerPart@equiv // Flatten;
unified    = mcsegs //. rules;
f          = Nearest[vxPos -> Automatic]; 
vxsForMask = Map[f[#, {Infinity, p[disk, 5/4]}] &, 
                 ImageValuePositions[Image@unified, #] & /@ Range@Max@unified, {2}]; 
edgesFin = Rule @@@ DeleteCases[(Flatten /@ Union /@ vxsForMask /. {x_} :> {x, x}), {}];
GraphicsRow[{i, 
            Colorize[unified, ColorFunction -> ColorData@10,ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
            GraphPlot[edgesFin, VertexCoordinateRules -> vxRules, 
                      MultiedgeStyle -> 1/3, VertexLabeling -> True]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When running it on your image:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm using GraphPlot because in v9 multigraphs aren't supported

---

Finally, here you have the code "conveniently" packed into functions (usage example at the end)

```
p[disk_, fraction_] := IntegerPart[disk fraction](*proportionalty*)
g[x_, r___] := Graphics[x, PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, idi}], ImageSize -> idi, r]

getProblemParms[i_Image] := 
 Module[{idi, vertexI, disk, vxRules, vxPos},
  idi = ImageDimensions@i;
  vertexI = SelectComponents[i, "Count", 5 < # < 100 &];
  disk = 20 (*find some heuristics to ensure a proper vertex occlusion radii*);
  vxRules = ComponentMeasurements[vertexI, "Centroid"];
  vxPos = Range@Length@vxRules /. vxRules;
  {idi, disk, vxRules, vxPos}
  ]

getMasks[i_Image, disk_, vxPos_] := Module[{i1, i2, edges, getMask},
  getMask[edges_, edge_] := SelectComponents[edges, {"Label", "Mask"}, #1 == edge &];
  i1 = Binarize[Show[i, g[{White, Disk[#, disk] & /@ vxPos}]]];
  i2 = ColorNegate@Erosion[i1, 1];
  edges = MorphologicalComponents@DeleteSmallComponents[i2, 30];
  (*masks "preserve" the mask number*)
  getMask[edges, #] & /@ Range@Max@Flatten@edges
  ]

collectEdgesForests[masks_, disk_] := 
 Module[{mIm, tm, mbp, posMbp, mbpClustered, segs},
  mIm = Image@Total@masks;
  tm = Thinning@mIm;
  mbp = MorphologicalTransform[Binarize@tm, "SkeletonBranchPoints"];
  posMbp = ImageValuePositions[mbp, 1];
  (*get the "unique" branch points,
  like clustering by taking the mean of near points*)
  mbpClustered = Union@MeanShift[ImageValuePositions[mbp, 1], p[disk, 1/2]];
  (*Get the whole image of all multiples occluding branch points*)
  (*segs "preserve" the mask number*)
  segs = ImageMultiply[tm, Binarize@g[{Black, Disk[#1, p[disk, 1/4]] & /@ mbpClustered}]];
  {mbpClustered, MorphologicalComponents[segs]}
  ]

findContinuations[i_Image, disk_, idi_, branchPoint_, mcsegs_] := 
 Module[{mm, coSegs, segmentsAtBranchPoint, tails, tgs, dests, a, b, 
   x}, 
   mm = Binarize@ Image[g[{White, Disk[branchPoint, p[disk, 2/5]]}, 
                        Background -> Black], ImageSize -> idi];
  coSegs = ImageMultiply[Image@mcsegs, mm];
  segmentsAtBranchPoint = Select[Union@Flatten[ImageData@coSegs], # != 0 &];
  tails = Position[ImageData@coSegs, #] & /@ segmentsAtBranchPoint;
  tgs = a /. FindFit[#, a x + b, {a, b}, x] & /@ tails;
  dests = Nearest[tgs -> segmentsAtBranchPoint, #, 2][[2]] & /@ tgs;
  Sort /@ Transpose[{segmentsAtBranchPoint, dests}] // Union]

getEdges[i_Image, disk_, idi_, mbpClustered_, mcsegs_, vxPos_] := 
 Module[{fc, equiv, rules, unified, f, vxsForMask},
  fc = findContinuations[i, disk, idi, #, mcsegs] & /@ mbpClustered;
  equiv = Flatten /@ Gather[Flatten[fc, 1], Intersection[#1, #2] =!= {} &];
  rules = Reverse /@ Thread[First@# -> Rest@#] & /@ IntegerPart@equiv // Flatten;
  unified = mcsegs //. rules;
  f = Nearest[vxPos -> Automatic];
  vxsForMask = Map[f[#, {Infinity, p[disk, 5/4]}] &, 
    ImageValuePositions[Image@unified, #] & /@ Range@Max@unified, {2}];
  Rule @@@ DeleteCases[(Flatten /@ Union /@ vxsForMask /. {x_} :> {x, x}), {}]
  ]

    (*Usage*)

  i = Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/58hg7.png";
  i = Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDby8.png";
  {idi, disk, vxRules, vxPos} = getProblemParms[i];
  masks = getMasks[i, disk, vxPos];
  {branchPoints, allEdgeSegments} = collectEdgesForests[masks, disk];
  edgesFin = getEdges[i, disk, idi, branchPoints, allEdgeSegments, vxPos];
  GraphPlot[edgesFin, VertexCoordinateRules -> vxRules, 
   MultiedgeStyle -> 1/3, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Comment: Oh~god.How nice work!You move me again!Just lost a "]" before "in" (*Usage*) .And I will give you another 100 bounties as my promise.

Comment: But how to I give you?Sad...

Comment: @yode Thanks :) And sorry, it was a copy/paste error

Answer (score 3):

There are some litte verbose,But anyway I made it.And the best method is belong to Dr. belisarius still.I'll refine it sometime in the future.

Get the disconnect binarize image.

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/58hg7.png"]
bin = Binarize[pic];
vert = ComponentMeasurements[
   samll = SelectComponents[bin, "Count", 5 < # < 100 &], "Centroid"];
disconnect = 
 DeleteSmallComponents[
  ImageSubtract[bin // ColorNegate // Thinning, Dilation[samll, 10]], 
  2]
```

[image]

Get these have a cross point's components.

```
commask = 
  Binarize@*Image /@ Values[ComponentMeasurements[disconnect, "Mask"]];
cross = Select[commask, 
  ImageMeasurements[MorphologicalBranchPoints[#], "Total"] > 1 &]
```

[image]

Get its ordering point corresponding the cross point is a hardest part of this solution.

```
pos1 = PixelValuePositions[#, 1] & /@ 
   MorphologicalTransform[Complement[commask, cross], "EndPoints"];
crossdis = 
  MapThread[
   ImageSubtract, {cross, 
    Dilation[MorphologicalBranchPoints[#], 3] & /@ cross}];
crossmask = 
  Binarize@*Image /@ Values[ComponentMeasurements[#, "Mask"]] & /@ 
   crossdis;
pointsetdis = 
  MapThread[
   Nearest[PixelValuePositions[MorphologicalTransform[#, "EndPoints"],
       1], Mean[
      PixelValuePositions[MorphologicalBranchPoints[#2], 1]], 
     4] &, {crossdis, cross}];
pointsetpos2 = 
  Table[PixelValuePositions[#, 
      1] & /@ (MorphologicalTransform[#, "EndPoints"] & /@ 
      mask), {mask, crossmask}];
orderpointsetpos2 = 
 MapThread[
  Function[{pre, pos}, 
   Catenate@
    MapThread[
     Complement, {Catenate[Select[pre, MemberQ[#]] & /@ pos], 
      List /@ pos}]], {pointsetpos2, pointsetdis}]
```

> {{{239, 90}, {165, 25}, {357, 120}, {337, 30}}}

Group it every two point.And The function of `order` origin from @Dr. belisarius.

```
order[l_List] := Module[{k, f}, k = Subsets[Range@Length@l, {2}];
  f = Nearest[# -> Range@Length@#] &[
    EuclideanDistance @@ l[[#]] & /@ k];
  k[[f[3.14, Length[l]/2]]]]
pos2order = 
 MapThread[
  order@Table[
     ArcTan @@ (com= 
        PixelValuePositions[Image@MorphologicalComponents[#1], 
         PixelValue[Image@MorphologicalComponents[#1], pt]];
       N@Mean[Select[com, Norm[# - pt] < 20 &]] - 
        pt), {pt, #2}] &, {crossdis, orderpointsetpos2}]
{{{2, 3}, {1, 4}}}
```

Get all pairs about vertexs

```
pos2 = MapThread[
   Function[p, Part[#1, p]] /@ #2 &, {orderpointsetpos2, pos2order}];
pos = Fold[Join[#1, #2] &, pos1, pos2];
subt = Fold[#1 /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} /; 
      EuclideanDistance[{a, b}, Last[#2]] < 20 -> First[#2] &, pos, 
  vert]
{{5, 7}, {4, 7}, {5, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 
  3}, {7, 3}, {4, 6}}
```

Then we get it.

```
Graph[Range@Length@vert, UndirectedEdge @@@ subt, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Values[vert], GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram"]
```

[image]