# Find the first n pairs in a list whose difference is the nearest to some number

Tags: list-manipulation

This is my list:

```
list = {2.6135182051634342, -2.6690957180727297, 
   0.26060239174734157, -0.4182243295792278};
```

I wanna gather it every two number,which make this group's diffrence's absolute value is nearest 3.14.

We can see this distance martix.

```
 DistanceMatrix[list, 
      DistanceFunction -> (First[Abs[#1 - #2]] &)] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

As we see.The  $(1st,4th)$ and $(2nd,3rd)$ is we want to group.Implies we result is `{{2.6135182051634342,-0.4182243295792278},{-2.6690957180727297,0.26060239174734157}}`

But this code doesn't work,becuase the `Nearest`'s first parameter cannot be a matrix.

```
mat = DistanceMatrix[list, 
   DistanceFunction -> (First[Abs[#1 - #2]] &)];
Position[mat, Nearest[mat, 3.14, 2]]
```

Or there are other more better method to do this?

---

Let's extended this topic.Assumption we have a `list2` like this.But wanna group it every two element that make its sum nearest 100.So how to do it?

```
SeedRandom[2016317];
list2 = RandomSample[Range@100, 20];
DistanceMatrix[list, 
  DistanceFunction -> (First[Plus[#1, #2]] &)] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Can we don't set a threshold value?Because the value is not easy to confirm at times.

Comment: You didn't mention **"without element repetitions"** in your first formulation of the question. Moving target questions are generally frowned upon here and I, for one, don't answer them anymore as they are an endless process.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius The poor language competence undermining me.I didn't deliberately frown you.Actually the function is used in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110354/21532) to judge whether two points are in a line.I felt very very upset for letting you down.And I post a [new quetion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110586/how-to-gather-a-list-whitout-no-repeat-element-to-nearest-a-certain-number) for this "new target".

Comment: Ok, no prob. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[l_List, nbr_Integer, near_Real] := Module[{k, f},
  k = Subsets[Range@Length@l, {2}]; 
  f = Nearest[# -> Range@Length@#] &[EuclideanDistance @@ l[[#]] & /@ k];
  k[[f[near, nbr]]]
  ]

list = {2.6135182051634342, -2.6690957180727297, 
       0.26060239174734157, -0.4182243295792278};

f[list, 2, N@Pi]

(* {{1, 4}, {2, 3}} *)
```

Your other example:

```
SeedRandom[2016317];
list2 = RandomSample[Range@100, 20];
f[list2, 2, 100.]

(* {{14, 18}, {18, 20}} *)
```

Comment: we result is `{{2.6135182051634342,-0.4182243295792278},{-2.6690957180727297,0.26060239174734157}}`.Of course,your code can do it.

Comment: I'm sorry to cancel the acceptance.But some problem isn't be found before this.

Answer (score 3):

I'll show how to use `Nearest` for this, using the larger example.

```
SeedRandom[2016317];
list2 = RandomSample[Range@100, 20]

(* Out[1510]= {20, 42, 89, 8, 56, 96, 39, 21, 40, 76, 62, 14, 51, 5,
  66, 84, 73, 99, 37, 7} *)

nf = Nearest[list2];
```

Now we use the fact that the `NearestFunction` can take a list argument (shortcut for mapping in this case) when dimensions are appropriate. For each element we want to find the one(s) that with it sum closest to 100.

```
nf[100 - list2]

(* Out[1507]= {{76, 84}, {56}, {8, 
  14}, {89}, {42}, {5}, {62}, {76}, {62}, {21}, {39, 
  37}, {84}, {51}, {96}, {37}, {14}, {21}, {5}, {62}, {96}} *)
```

--- edit ---

Here is how one can restrict so that we only keep values that come within a threshold of the goal. I'll also use `Map` so that this will work in versions prior to Mathematica 10.1 or so.

```
Cases[
 Map[{#, nf[100 - #, {Infinity, 1.5}]} &, list2], {_, {__}}]

(* Out[1590]= {{96, {5}}, {39, {62}}, {62, {39, 
   37}}, {5, {96}}, {37, {62}}} *)
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: Fails on v9. Is it a v10 feature?

Comment: The listability is, yes. In v9 I guess use `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I'm very sorry for misunderstanding your meaning.As the Dr.belisarius's coustom function `f`,I can get the result like this `list2[[#]]&/@f[list2,2,100.]`.But you?

Comment: Why not also show the version for **10.1** and above