# Including the actual length scale of the image in processing microscopic images

Tags: image-processing

Following the wonderful methodologies provided in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/203517/52181), I have learned how to process microscopic images of the types shown below in order to analyze them. When it comes to analysing the size distribution of the particles, the images always have a scale indicator, which give the actual scale of the image. By default, when we measure the size distribution e.g. using `ComponentMeasurements`, everything is measured in pixels. My question is:

- Is there a way to incorporate/detect in Mathematica the actual given length-scale of the image? (in example below $500 nm$ for the shown spacing), that is, to convert pixels to $nm$ (or $nm^2$ for area). Example given below ([source](http://www.cytodiagnostics.com/store/pc/60nm-Standard-Gold-Nanoparticles-500ml-p1016.htm)):

[image]

---

To detect the particles, I've adopted the following approach learned from [Niki Estner's previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203688/52181):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryzmV.jpg"]
ridges = RidgeFilter[-img, 1];
distRidges = 
  DistanceTransform@ColorNegate@MorphologicalBinarize[ridges];
distMax = MaxDetect[distRidges, 1];
morph = WatershedComponents[ridges, distMax, Method -> "Basins"];
comp = ComponentMeasurements[{img, morph}, {"Centroid", "Neighbors"}];

edges = Dilation[EdgeDetect[Image[morph], 1, .001], 0.5];
edgeOverlay = 
 Show[img, SetAlphaChannel[ColorReplace[edges, White -> Red], edges]]
```

yielding the following detection result:

[image]

and to extract the particle sizes in order to estimate the size distribution histogram, I've used the "Area" property in `ComponentMeasurements` as follows:

```
sizesls = {};
areaInPixels = ComponentMeasurements[morph, {"Area"}];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[areaInPixels], i++,
  eltmp = areaInPixels[[i]][[2]];
  AppendTo[sizesls, eltmp[[1]]];
  ];
Histogram[sizels]
```

[image]

but the size distribution is obtained in pixels, as opposed to using the actual scale of the image in $nm$ as indicated in the original image. From the source of the image, the indicated expected mean particle size is $60 nm.$

Comment: I think it is necessary to perform a verification on whatever algorithm you use.  This could be done by taking a screenshot of, say, the lower left quadrant of the picture, printing it out at maximum size (maximally filling an 8.5" x 11" sheet of paper), and manually determining the size of each particle. [Say, outline each in pen, measure the min & max dia. of each with a ruler, then average.] Then compare that with size distributions found by the various algorithms, applied to that same screenshot (or, better, you could do this for all four quadrants).   Have you done this?

Comment: @theorist Hi, to verify I've overlaid the extracted portion on top of the original image to make sure they overlap perfectly. And it has been a successful test, is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi @user929304. No, I meant that you need some completely independent verification that your algorithm is accurate, & one approach is to manually (by hand) measure the sizes, and compare those measurements to MMA's. To accurately measure the sizes manually, you need to enlarge the picture as much as reasonably possible. Ideally, you'd take the entire original image (w/o the MMA overlay), and print it on a poster printer (@~24" x 36"). Then you (or a grad student!) would manually measure each particle. And (unlike most algorithms) you have the judgement not to be fooled by overlaps, holes, etc.

Comment: I.e., especially if you plan to use this in a publication, you need some sort of verification that is completely independent of the algorithm. The fact that different algorithms give different results tells you that you need some independent way of determining which, if any, of the algorithms give a result that corresponds to reality. Any good reviewer will request this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I would exclude the scale from the "particle search algorithm", like this:

```
imgWithScale = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryzmV.jpg"];
img = ImageTake[imgWithScale, 280]
```

(followed by the same steps you used above).

Then I would extract the nm/pixel scale:

```
scaleArea = ImageTake[imgWithScale, {-20, -15}]
whitePixels = PixelValuePositions[Binarize[scaleArea], 1];
{left, right} = MinMax[whitePixels[[All, 1]]];
nmPerPx = 500./(right - left)
```

(Note that I'm using [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) array access (`[[All, ...`) instead `For` loops to extract specific elements from a nested list. This is almost always shorter, faster and more readable. Never use `For` in Mathematica)

Next, I'm not sure the `Area` is the best measure of particle size. Your particles are mostly ciruclar, so we can try a few others:

```
measurements = {"EquivalentDiskRadius", "MeanCentroidDistance", 
   "Length", "CaliperLength", "BoundingDiskRadius", "MeanIntensity"};
(* MeanIntensity is dimensionless, the other ones are lengths, 
   i.e scaled by nmPerPx^1 *) 
scale = nmPerPx^{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}; 
(* only count particles that aren't clipped by an image border, with 
   condition #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 & *)
comp = ComponentMeasurements[{img, morph}, measurements, #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 &]; 
Multicolumn[
 MapThread[
  Histogram[#1, PlotLabel -> #2, ImageSize -> 300] & , {scale*
    Transpose[comp[[All, 2]]], measurements}]]
```

[image]

(I've used `EquivalentDiskRadius`, the radius of a disk with the same area, so it's easier to compare with the other lengths.)

It seems that `Length` and `CaliperLength` are much better estimates for the particle size, because they are less dependent on occlusion.

We can also easily see that there's a correlation between intensity (i.e. depth) and size:

```
compare = {4, 6};
ListPlot[comp[[All, 2, compare]], 
 AxesLabel -> measurements[[compare]]]
```

[image]

If you want to explore the correlation further, you can use `LocatorPane` and `Dynamic` to see which component is where interactively:

```
nfIdx = Nearest[comp[[All, 2, compare]] -> comp[[All, 1]]];
nf = Nearest[comp[[All, 2, compare]]];    
pt = comp[[1, 2, compare]];

Row[{
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
   Dynamic[ListPlot[comp[[All, 2, compare]], 
     AxesLabel -> measurements[[compare]], GridLines -> nf[pt], 
     ImageSize -> 500]]],
  Dynamic[
   HighlightImage[img, 
    ColorNegate[Binarize[Image[(morph - nfIdx[pt][[1]])^2], 0]], 
    ImageSize -> 400], TrackedSymbols :> {pt}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy scaleArea...

Comment: Very nice! Your last interactive plot seems to include holes as well as particles.   Are these holes included in your CaliperLength histogram and, if so, might they be eliminated by filtering out shapes showing concavity?

Comment: @NikiEstner Hello! I am late to this post, but this has been a wonderful learning experience for me. I am doing a similar processing on micrographs and wanted to ask, if your approach can be extended to estimate the shortest surface surface separation between the found components? (if this may be too different of a problem, I can post as new question). Look forward to any feedback on this, thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

You could extract the conversion factor in a semi-automated way.

```
imgcrop = ImageTake[img, {-20, -15}, {-150, -1}]
```

[image]

```
bars = MorphologicalComponents[imgcrop, .1];
Image@bars
```

[image]

The x-coordinates of the centroids of the bars are then

```
xcoords = ComponentMeasurements[bars, "Centroid"][[All, 2, 1]]
  (* {0.5, 16., 31.8, 47.0556, 63., 79., 95., 110., 126., 142.} *)
```

And the mean difference between x-coordinates of successive bars is

```
Mean[Differences[xcoords]]
  (* 15.7222 *)
```

The conversion factor in nanometers/pixel is (assuming I'm reading the scale right and each space between the ticks is 500 nm)

```
nmPerPixel = 500/Mean[Differences[xcoords]]
  (* 31.8021 *)
```

Then, from your image analysis, the areas in pixels are

```
areaPixels = 
  Flatten[ComponentMeasurements[morph, {"Area"}][[All, 2]]];
```

And the areas converted to square nanometers

```
areaSqNanometers = nmPerPixel^2 areaPixels;
Histogram[areaSqNanometers]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find scaling coefficient from your *.jpg by using Coordinate Tools. Place cursor on first tick of scale, horizontal coordinate is 234, last tick corresponds to 391. So, scaling coefficient is `hscale=500./(391-234)`. Assumimg that area has a shape of circle, `Histogram` command can be simplified to

```
 areaInPixels[[All, 2]] // Flatten // hscale Sqrt[4 #/\[Pi]] & // Histogram
```

which gives this distribution of sizes. Mean size is about 60 nm.

[image]